# Getting error while tagging docker image using variable as parameter

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, docker-tag

I am using below piece of code for building, tagging and pushing the docker image.

```
docker.withRegistry('https://servername', envcred) {
        def pytunzip = docker.build("servername/${env}/${imgname}:latest", "-f ./image-creation-artifacts/${imgname} ./image-creation-artifacts")
        pytunzip.push()     
        pytunzip.tag(env.BUILD_NUMBER)
        pytunzip.push(env.BUILD_NUMBER)
}
```

This was working fine till few days back. Now all of a sudden it's throwing below error while tagging.

```
No such property: imgver for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

Below is the detailed error -

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: imgver for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:242)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:288)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:292)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.buildimg(WorkflowScript:195)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker.withRegistry(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/docker-workflow/WEB-INF/lib/docker-workflow.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy:41)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor358.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Also, this code works fine when I directly pass value instead of a variable. Like this -

```
docker.withRegistry('https://servername', envcred) {
        def pytunzip = docker.build("servername/${env}/${imgname}:latest", "-f ./image-creation-artifacts/${imgname} ./image-creation-artifacts")
        pytunzip.push()
        pytunzip.tag("v123")
        pytunzip.push("v123")
    }
```

I have come across similar posts but I cannot downgrade or upgrade any plugin in Jenkins as of now. Currently I am using **2.138.1** Jenkins version. Can you please suggest what could be the issue or if I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: It's not clear where you are taking the value of imgver; if it's a variable then use $imgver ; else enclose in quotes

Comment: See if `println imgver` before `pytunzip.tag(imgver)` gets you somewhere.

Comment: @dheerajtripathi it's a variable. I tried with `$imgver` , `${imgver}` and `"${imgver}"` as well. It's still failing with same error.

Comment: @MaratC I am not able to print just before `pytunzip.tag(imgver)`. What do you think the issue is?

Comment: So now I got this piece of code working just by changing variable name and declaring it within the function instead globally. But now I am trying to replace it  with `env.BUILD_NUMBER`, it's failing with same error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I got this working just by removing "env." from `env.BUILD_NUMBER`. I have been using "env." for accessing the environment variable `WORKSPACE` but for some reason it was not working for  `BUILD_NUMBER`.